# How to adjust adjust the width of 2 side-by-side elements to fit the container

Tags: css

I have 2 divs inside of another div. The two inner divs are displaying text, which is generated by my application. The length of the text varies. Is there any way to force one inner div, let's say the first one, to fill the space leftover by the second inner div?

If that sounds cryptic, take the below example... the width of the score box varies in width depending on what is displayed.. 0% being short, 100% being long...

How do I ensure the button on the left fills the leftover space to make things fit tightly into the blue box.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way I know of to do this with variable widths is to use faux tables:

```
<div id="stuff">
 <div id="name">Jesse James</div>
 <div id="percent">100%</div>
</div>


#stuff { display: table; width: 200px; }
#stuff #name { display: table-cell; width: 100%; background: gray; }
#stuff #percent { display: table-cell; background: red; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/chovy/HMnSq/